# Composer - Default option for dev requirements

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, composer-php

**I noticed that ...**

When I run '`composer help update`' It tells me that the `--dev` option is enabled by default

```
 --dev  Enables installation of require-dev packages (enabled by default, only present for sanity).
```

Which is not the case for the '`composer install`' command, where `--no-dev` is enabled,

```
--no-dev Disables installation of require-dev packages (enabled by default, only present for sanity).
```

**So, I was wondering ...**

Why the default behavior for `update` and `install` is different for dev requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [release notes](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0.0-alpha7/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha7-2013-05-04) of the last release (alpha7), the install package will start defaulting to --dev as well in the near future. The reason they are not the same at the moment was to allow a transitional phase.